# How to avoid overfull \hbox warning?

Tags: boxes, warnings

The following code compiles but throws this error/warning :
Overfull \hbox (7.65448pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 21--21

Visually there is nothing wrong though, and the box does not cross the page margins ?
How can I avoid this error without messing things up ?

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper,english,dutch,leqno]{article}

\usepackage[top=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=1.5cm,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{vanillegeel}{RGB}{255,240,216}
\definecolor{appelsien}{RGB}{255,160,8}

\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\noindent\fcolorbox{appelsien}{vanillegeel}{\begin{tabular}{ll}\hspace{-1.9mm}\parbox{3.4cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.13]{SABENA-logo_origineel.pdf}}
& \parbox{11.8cm}{{\footnotesize\bf\emph{\reflectbox{S}$\mspace{-1mu}$abena}-lijnen ?!}\\
\footnotesize Vermits ik nergens een benaming vond voor de karakteristieke 'uitgerokken gespiegelde S\nobreakdash-lijnen' die radioreflecties op lijnvliegtuigen in spectrogrammen vertonen, wees me iemand (\emph{Georges De Greef}) op de vormgelijkenis met een bekende logo van de ter ziele gegane nationale luchtvaartmaatschappij \emph{Soci\'{e}t\'{e} Anonyme Belge d'Exploitation de la Navigation A\'{e}rienne} (1923\nobreakdash-2001), wat me inspireerde om de \emph{Doppler}-signaallijnen dan maar '\,\emph{\reflectbox{S}$\mspace{-1mu}$abena}-lijnen' te noemen.\\
De gespiegelde beginletter benadrukt de vormgelijkenis.\\
De titel-illustratie verwijst eveneens naar de SABENA-logo.}\end{tabular}\hspace{-1.6mm}}
\end{center}

% If needed, the embedded PDF image can be found at :
% https://dl.dropbox.com/u/52458256/SABENA-logo_origineel.pdf

\end{document}
```

Comment: Most likely your parboxes get overfull. Add the `draft` option to the `\documentclass` command.

Comment: The image is too wide for the `\parbox`. As the box is 3.4cm wide, specify the width of the image to something less, e.g. `width=3.3cm` instead of using `scale=0.13`.

Comment: I would just like to add that suppressing hyphenation will always lead to problems. You should at the very least use `\usepackage{microtype}`. But I recommend to allow hyphenation: add `[dutch]` option to `{babel}` and remove `{hyphenat}` completely.

Comment: Latex's hyphenation in Dutch sux - it splits the words by syllables - a method dating back to the typewriter era. Nowadays we split words on word parts, and this can only be accomplished manually by switching the automatic hyphenation off.

Answer (score 5):

Your input is way too complicated:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,dutch,leqno]{article}

\usepackage[top=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=1.5cm,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{vanillegeel}{RGB}{255,240,216}
\definecolor{appelsien}{RGB}{255,160,8}

\newcommand{\Sabena}{%
  \ifdim\fontdimen1\font>0pt \kern.1em\fi
  \reflectbox{S}%
  \ifdim\fontdimen1\font>0pt \kern-.1em\fi
  abena}



\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fcolorbox{appelsien}{vanillegeel}{\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  \adjustbox{valign=c}{\includegraphics[width=3.4cm]{SABENA-logo_origineel.pdf}} &
  \parbox{11.8cm}{\footnotesize
    \textbf{\emph{\Sabena}-lijnen}?!

    Vermits ik nergens een benaming vond voor de karakteristieke 
    'uitgerokken gespiegelde S\nobreakdash-lijnen' die radioreflecties
    op lijnvliegtuigen in spectrogrammen vertonen, wees me iemand 
    (\emph{Georges De Greef}) op de vormgelijkenis met een bekende logo
    van de ter ziele gegane nationale luchtvaartmaatschappij \emph{Soci\'{e}t\'{e}
    Anonyme Belge d'Exploitation de la Navigation A\'{e}rienne}
    (1923\nobreakdash-2001), wat me inspireerde om de
    \emph{Doppler}-signaallijnen dan maar `\emph{\Sabena}-lijnen'
    te noemen.

    De gespiegelde beginletter benadrukt de vormgelijkenis.
    De titel-illustratie verwijst eveneens naar de SABENA-logo.}
\end{tabular}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Notice that there's no need to back up by eye-computed spaces; all you need is to use `\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}` that will not add spaces at the sides of the `tabular`.

With `\adjustbox` we get perfect centering of the image.

The text is better treated by setting the font size at the start.

*Never* use the explicit `pdftex` option.

I've provided a definition for the `\Sabena` logo that will take care of some corrections when the font is slanted.

One might also do some better computations to make the box fill the entire line.

[image]