# Overfull hbox even with spaces

Tags: errors

Why is the following line giving me the `Overfull \hbox` error?  There are plenty of spaces.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
To extend our example from above, consider if we only had one hierarchy, "Product Characteristics".  The segments would include \{[Overall Segment], [Sports Equipment],[Books],..., [Sports Equipment:Baseball Equipment], [Sports Equipment:Football Equipment] ,..., [Sports Equipment:Baseball Equipment:Baseball Gloves] ,..., [Sports Equipment:Baseball Equipment:Baseball Gloves:Wilson Model X]\}, where the latter is our microsegment, and the level to which the input data would be aggregated.
\end{document}
```

[image: overleaf demo]

Comment: Welcome to TeXSE! It would be a huge help if you'd post a complete MWE (Minimal Working Example) that someone can compile to see the actual error.

Comment: Thanks! Okay, edited.

Comment: I got a clean compile from `pdfLaTeX` with no errors. I have to say that the use of math mode doesn't seem to make sense here, but that didn't throw an error or even a warning.

Comment: Hey, got the error with overleaf too, see edit... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like it may be a hyphenation problem. Search the site for "overfull box" and see what turns up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid overfull \hbox warning?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88862/how-to-avoid-overfull-hbox-warning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Does really had not be a space behind the colon? Adding them compilation not gives any warnings or bad boxes.
- Instead `...` is better to use `dots` which should be properly insertes as `, \dots,` :

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
To extend our example from above, consider if we only had one hierarchy,
"Product Characteristics".  The segments would include \{[Overall Segment],
[Sports Equipment], [Books], \dots, [Sports Equipment: Baseball Equipment],
[Sports Equipment: Football Equipment], \dots, [Sports Equipment: Baseball
Equipment: Baseball Gloves], \dots, [Sports Equipment: Baseball
Equipment: Baseball Gloves: Wilson Model X]\}, where the latter is our
microsegment, and the level to which the input data would be aggregated.
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: recent version of `documentclass` use `utf8` encoding by default, so you not need to load it.